# Different sounds play at different volumes in the same app

Tags: audio, volume

This just started happening, and it's affecting multiple apps.  On my Axon 7, certain sounds in certain apps are consistently playing at a louder volume than other sounds in the same app.  If I turn up the volume enough to hear those other sounds, the loud ones are deafening.  And all this is happening at the lowest volume settings.

Example: a Spider Solitaire app makes a shuffling sound when it deal the initial hand.  That's very loud.  But each time you deal a new round within a hand, it makes a similar sound, and that plays normally.  It's as if there are multiple sound players, and the app doles out sounds to different ones.  And one of them is set louder than the others.  Does that make sense?  Is that how sound playing in apps works?

It seems like a reboot fixed this one time, but it came back, and rebooting doesn't help now.  I've tried wiping cache.  Don't want to factory reset unless I have too (does factory reset wipe data too?).

Comment: Just tried disabling the Dolby Atmos feature of the phone, and the issue isn't there without it.  But it returns when it's reenabled.

Answer (score 1):

False alarm.  Turns out the Dolby Atmos module has a 'volume leveler' feature that I must have turned on.  It's hidden behind the equalizer screen.  Anyway, turning that off returned things to normal.